# How to create native module for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-gyp

I want to create my own native Nodejs module. I have been following http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/addons.html  and try to understand how to create native module .

First created hello.cc

```
#include <node.h>
#include <v8.h>
using namespace v8;
Handle<Value> Method(const Arguments& args) {
 HandleScope scope;
 return scope.Close(String::New("world"));
}

void init(Handle<Object> exports) {
  exports->Set(String::NewSymbol("hello"),
  FunctionTemplate::New(Method)->GetFunction());
}

    NODE_MODULE(hello, init)
```

Then created binding.gyp

```
 {
   "targets": [
   {
     "target_name": "hello",
     "sources": [ "hello.cc" ]
   }
  ]
 }
```

Then I ran these command

```
node-gyp configure
node-gyp build
```

finally created hello.js

```
     var addon = require('./build/Release/hello');
      console.log(addon.hello());
```

At this time I got error like

```
 module.js:355
 Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
```

and so on.

Comment: I still haven't tried, but have you read [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/writing-nodejs-addons--cms-21771)?

Comment: Nope I'll go through it. thank you

Comment: The error you posted in the line that throws the error, but doesn't actually include the error message itself, please update it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to build your example but I don't achieve to complete because of V8 versions.

So I followed the [nodejs addon example](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/addons.html) again. Today the example is a little different at yours. And all works right.

My environment is the following:

- SO: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
- nodejs v0.12.7
- node-gyp v2.0.2
- Python 2.7.6
- gcc 4.8.4
- CPU Architecture: x86_64
- CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit
- Byte Order: Little Endian

I hope this will be useful.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check that out

Answer (score 0):

I guess your example comes from following [this](http://www.benfarrell.com/2013/01/03/c-and-node-js-an-unholy-combination-but-oh-so-right/) tutorial, problem is that I get several compiler errors that seems to be due to missing imports on the current release of `node`:

```
../hello.cc:7:15: error: calling a protected constructor of class 'v8::HandleScope'
  HandleScope scope;
              ^
/Users/admin/.node-gyp/4.2.6/include/node/v8.h:885:13: note: declared protected here
  V8_INLINE HandleScope() {}
            ^
../hello.cc:8:16: error: no member named 'Close' in 'v8::HandleScope'
  return scope.Close(String::New("world"));
         ~~~~~ ^
../hello.cc:8:30: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
  return scope.Close(String::New("world"));
                     ~~~~~~~~^
../hello.cc:13:29: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'v8::Isolate *' with an lvalue of type 'Handle<v8::Value> (const v8::internal::Arguments &)'
      FunctionTemplate::New(Method)->GetFunction());
                            ^~~~~~
/Users/admin/.node-gyp/4.2.6/include/node/v8.h:4350:16: note: passing argument to parameter 'isolate' here
      Isolate* isolate, FunctionCallback callback = 0,
               ^
../hello.cc:12:23: error: no member named 'NewSymbol' in 'v8::String'
  target->Set(String::NewSymbol("hello"),
              ~~~~~~~~^
In file included from ../hello.cc:1:
In file included from /Users/admin/.node-gyp/4.2.6/include/node/node.h:42:
/Users/admin/.node-gyp/4.2.6/include/node/v8.h:327:9: error: cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'v8::FunctionTemplate *' with an lvalue of type 'const char *'
      : val_(that) {}
        ^    ~~~~
../hello.cc:8:34: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate>::Local<const char>' requested here
  return scope.Close(String::New("world"));
```

Node version is

```
macbookproloreto:native admin$ node -v
v4.2.6
```

while `node-gyp` is

```
macbookproloreto:native admin$ node-gyp -v
v3.3.1
```